# Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined when changing JSON

Tags: javascript, html

I've been looking at other threads on stackoverflow with the same issues and tried the solution, but havent worked out. I tried wrapping it inside the window.onload function, but still didnt work.
When i print it out with console.log it shows the element, so i dont understand why its undefined.

It got undefined when i changed the JSON location of the data from:

```
https://mysite?action=getMedia&type=photo
```

to

```
https://mysite?action=getMedia
```

Without doing that change, it worked fine and now i cant find out whats actually causing the problem that my element it undefined.

This is my **JS** code

```
$.getJSON('https://mysite?action=getMedia', function(data) {
  console.log(data)
  if(data.files.length == 0){
    document.getElementById("Nouploadedfiles").style.display = "block"
  }else{
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++){
        if(data.files[i].type == "photo")
        {
          var stringOftitle = data.files[i].title;
          var title = document.createElement("h3");
          title.innerHTML = stringOftitle;
          console.log(title)
          var path = data.files[i].path;
          var completepath = "https://ddwap.mah.se/AH0361/" + path;
          console.log(completepath);
          var Image = document.createElement("img")
          var thumbnail = document.createElement("div")
          var caption = document.createElement("div");
          caption.setAttribute('class', 'caption text-center');
          thumbnail.setAttribute("class", "thumbnail")
          Image.setAttribute("src", completepath)
          Image.setAttribute("class", "img-responsive photofiles")
          document.getElementById("photodiv").appendChild(thumbnail);
          document.getElementsByClassName("thumbnail")[i].appendChild(caption);
          document.getElementsByClassName("thumbnail")[i].appendChild(Image);
          document.getElementsByClassName("caption")[i].appendChild(title);

        }else if(data.files[i].type == "audio"){
          console.log("True audio")

        }else if(data.files[i].type == "video"){
          console.log("True video")

        }
        else{
          console.log("Something went wrong")
        }
     }
  }

    });
```

This is the **HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://oss.maxcdn.com/jquery.form/3.50/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css"> </link>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">

            <!-- Navigation -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Film-appen</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">

                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html"></i> Start</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="filmbiblio.html"></i> Mitt filmbibliotek</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="inst.html"></i> inställningar</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"></i> Mina uppladdningar</a>
                        </li>
                        <div class="container" id="userinfo">
                          <p><strong>Användare:</strong></p>
                          <p> Philip </p>
                          <p><strong>Favoritfilm:</strong></p>
                          <p id="getFavMovie">  </p>
                        </div>
               </div>
          </nav>
     </div>
     <div class="container" id="imageuploads">
       <div class="form-group">
         <h4 class="text-center"> Välj vilka objekt du vill visa här </h4>
         <select name="type" id="selectedfiles" class="form-control">
           <option value="">Välj objekt här</option>
           <option value="photo">Foto</option>
           <option value="video">Video</option>
           <option value="audio">Ljud</option>
         </select>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-12" id="photodiv">

       </div>
       <div id="Nouploadedfiles" class="text-center">
         <h2> Du har inga uppladdade filer </h2>
       </div>
     </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
<script src="js.js"> </script>
```

Since im creating the elements dynamically, it should in my opinion be defined. I guess the HTML file isnt necessary but ill post it anyways.

Comment: Please share structure of  `data`

Comment: I can't find any element with `id="photodiv"` in JS nor in HTML did you omit part of it ? or is it the problem since `document.getElementById("photodiv")` is undefined :p

Comment: You're giving the error but you're not telling which line it is happening on. There are at least four different lines where the error could happen that include ".appendChild". Be specific and include the line. In any case, it is likely because there's no element with `id="photodiv"` in your HTML.

Comment: @Roope Its on all these lines

          document.getElementsByClassName("thumbnail")[i].appendChild(caption);
          document.getElementsByClassName("thumbnail")[i].appendChild(Image);
          document.getElementsByClassName("caption")[i].appendChild(title);

Comment: @jonatjano sorry wrong html file, fixed now

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: why don't you use line like `thumbnail.appendChild(caption)`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer, this might help someone.
Since the data from the JSON file were not only `type=photo` but all kinds of media. So when the foor loop ran, and hit the else if statement, i++ was incremented by 1. 
This means that when the if statement hit the `data.files[i].type == "photo"` after it hit the `data.files[i].type == "audio"` it was not `0`, but `1` which made the `document.getElementsByClassName("thumbnail")[i].appendChild(caption);` not exist since `i = 1` and not `i = 0`

Solution was simple, create a variable outside the loop `var lengthofElements = 0` and use that instead of `i` in the appendchild.

Answer (score 0):

You first create the elements `thumbnail` and `caption` with `document.createElement()`. Then you instantly try to look for said elements in the document. But since you have not added the created elements into the document, they will not be found. Thus, `getElementByClass()` will return `undefined`.

I.e. you cannot find an element with class `thumbnail` in the document because you have not added the element to it. Thus, you also cannot add the element with class `caption` to that element, and so the second element will not be found either.

Comment: Appreciate your effort, but that was not the problem :)